# Programmatically install with bower?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, gruntjs

I'm writing a grunt task and I want to install a dependency programmatically. However, I can't seem to figure out how to use their API.

This works just fine, but parsing the response is brittle because it uses the CLI:

```
grunt.util.spawn({
  cmd: 'bower',
  args: ['install', '--save', 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git']
}, function(none, message) {
  grunt.log.writeln(message);
});
```

This does not work:

```
bower.commands.install.line(['--save', 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git'])
    .on('end', function(data) {
      grunt.log.writeln(data);
      done();
    })
    .on('err', function(err) {
      grunt.log.fail(err);
      done();
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
$ grunt my-task
Running "my-task:default_options" (my-task) task
Fatal error: Could not find any dependencies
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `line()` function expects the whole argv, so should be:

`bower.commands.install.line(['node', 'bower', '--save', 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git']);`

However, you should rather just pass paths and options to the `install()` method directly:

`bower.commands.install(['git@github.com:foo/bar.git'], {save: true});`